# How to get active attributes active options in magento?

Tags: magento

How to get active attributes active options in magento?
How to show only attribute and attribute options like layered navigation left side block. it shows active attribute and options as per selected category only.

My code is toolbar.phtml

```
    <?php
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('customtoolbar/customtoolbar_general/enabled') == 1):
    ?>
                    <div class="filter-by" style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
                        <?php 
                            $entity_type_id =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
                            $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($entity_type_id)->addFieldToFilter("backend_type",array("eq"=>'int'))->addFieldToFilter("frontend_input",array("eq"=>'select'))->addFieldToFilter("used_for_filter_by",array("eq"=>'1'));
                        ?>
                        <table><tr><td>
                                    <label><?php echo $this->__('Shop By') ?></label></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select onchange="fillattvalue(this.value)" id="attributes" style="width: 82px;">
                                        <option value="select"><?php echo $this->__('Please Select') ?></option>
                                        <?php foreach($attributes as $attribute): ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $attribute->getAttributeCode(); ?>">
                                                <?php echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel() ?>
                                            </option>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </select></td>
                                <td id="attvalue" style="display: none; padding-left: 10px; "></td>
                            </tr></table>
                    </div>
                     <?php endif ?>









<script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function fillattvalue(item)
    {
        var parameters = {att_code : item }
        var url = '<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('customtoolbar/index/fillattvalues'); ?>';
        var e = document.getElementById("attributes");
        var select_index = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if(select_index == "select")
            {
            document.getElementById('attvalue').style.display='none';
        }
        else
            {
            document.getElementById('loading-mask').style.display = 'none';
            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                    method: 'post',
                    //asynchronous: false,
                    onSuccess: function(transport) {
                        document.getElementById('loading-mask').style.display='none';
                        if(transport.responseText) {
                            var response = transport.responseText;
                            response = response.evalJSON();
                            var total_length = response.length;
                            var html='';
                            var cur_url = location.href;
                            var cur_att = document.getElementById("attributes").value;
                            var cur_cat_url ='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getUrlPath() ?>'
                            html+= '<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)" style="width:82px">';
                            html+= '<option value="">Please Select</option>';
                            for (var i=1;i<total_length;i++){
                                var inner_parameters = {
                                    lable : response[i]['lable'],
                                    value : response[i]['value']
                                }
                                <?php $is_anchor = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getIsAnchor();
                                    if($is_anchor == 1){ ?>
                                    var baseURL = cur_cat_url + "?" + cur_att +"=" + response[i]['value'];
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                    //var baseURL = cur_url.substring(0, cur_url.indexOf('/', 14))+ "/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=" + response[i]['lable'];
                                    var baseURL =  '<?php  echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>' + "catalogsearch/advanced/result/?"+item+"[]=" + response[i]['value'];
                                    <?php } ?>
                                html+= '<option value="'+baseURL+'">';
                                html+= response[i]['lable'];
                                html+='</option>';
                            }
                            html+='</select>'
                            document.getElementById('attvalue').innerHTML=html; 
                            document.getElementById('loading-mask').style.display='none';
                            document.getElementById('attvalue').style.display='inline-block';
                        }
                    },
                    parameters:parameters
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

indexcontroller.php code is

```
<?php
    class Biztech_Customtoolbar_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            $this->loadLayout();     
            $this->renderLayout();
        }
        public function fillattvaluesAction()
        {
            $att_code  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('att_code');
            $json = array();
            $att = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $att_code);
            $options = $att->getSource()->getAllOptions();

            foreach($options as $option)
            {
                $json[] = array(
                    'lable' => $option['label'],
                    'value' => $option['value']
                );
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($json));
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a attribute to appear in navigation layer, following steps may help

1. Go to Catalog->manage products, Select any product, and Click on ‘Create New Attribute’
2. Create new attribute of your own, here I have taken ‘Manufacture’ as an example
3. Enter the Attribute information, In the frontend Properties section,
   a.   Set Catalog input type for store owner to “dropdown”
   b.   Use in Layered Navigation to one of the following: Filterable (with     results), Filterable (no results)
   c.   Set Use in Search Results Layered Navigation to “Yes”
4. Complete the ‘Manage /Label Options’ details
5. Save the configuration

Comment: i am currently using this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-product-grid-filters.html i these two files are from this extension.